# How to add event listener to Map marker[ ] array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a google map implementation that drops the pins on the map using a couple function calls and a marker[ ]  array.

It works great, but I can't figure out how to possibly add an onClick event or other type of event listener to the function since it doesn't have a marker variable defined explicitly.

Where would I be able to add something like this?:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function() {
window.location.href = this.url;};
```

Here is my basic map code and functions:

```
var pinlocations = [
  ['1', {lat: 30.266758, lng: -97.739080}, 12, '/establishments/1111'],
  ['2', {lat: 30.267178, lng: -97.739050}, 11, '/establishments/1222'],
  ['3', {lat: 30.267458, lng: -97.741231}, 10, '/establishments/1333'],
  ['4', {lat: 30.388880, lng: -97.892276}, 9, '/establishments/1444']
];

      var markers = [];
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: 30.267178, lng: -97.739050}
        });

      }

      function drop() {
        clearMarkers();
        for (var i = 0; i < pinlocations.length; i++) {
            var place = pinlocations[i];
            addMarkerWithTimeout(place[1], place[0], place[2], place[3], i * 200);
        }
      }

      function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, title, zindex, url, timeout) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            zIndex: zindex,
            url: url,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          }));  
        }, timeout); 
      }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple . This what you're looking for ?  marker.addListener('click', .....

Comment: @gvfordo That is the feature, but it doesn't show how to apply it to a full array of markers that are called through a function like I have.  It simply shows how to call an event on a single var marker.

Comment: assign your new maker to a var,  add the listener,  and push the var into your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add an event to an array, you have to add it to each element within the array. You can do this with the `.forEach()` array method:

```
// Iterate the markers array
markers.forEach(function(marker){
  // Set up a click event listener for each marker in the array
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = marker.url;
  });
});
```

Or, you could take another approach and add the event at the moment each individual marker gets created.

```
  function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, title, zindex, url, timeout) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: title,
        zIndex: zindex,
        url: url,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      }).addListener('click', function() {
        window.location.href = this.url;
      });  
    }, timeout); 
  }
```

Comment: Ok, would I add that in the initmap function, even though the array is null there?  Or would I need to add it into the drop() function, after the for loop there?

Comment: @Keith It's tough to say from the code you've shown. You could do it anytime after the array is fully populated OR you could take another approach and add the event at the moment each individual marker gets created. I'll update the answer to show that...

Comment: I think the second option is exactly what I need to do this cleanly.  It's not compiling for me though when I switch out the function.  Is there a syntax error in the snippet?

Comment: @Keith Ooops, yes. It was the copied reference to the `marker` loop variable, which doesn't exist in the second example. Changed to `this`.

Comment: I got it working with that, that's great.  You do have an extra semi-colon in the answer still though.  This });); should just be })); I  believe.  You might want to fix that for future visitors.  THX!

Comment: @Keith Actually it was a left over `);`. Answer updated.